# How to get Elasticsearch terms aggregation to filter multi value fields by the same method as an aggs filter

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm looking to create a query to give me all the top widgets in the widget field of my document to work with an autocomplete search.  It's a multi value field with a keyword tokenizer and an autocomplete tokenizer.

The issue I'm having getting the buckets to filter in the same way the aggs filter does.

Some example data, multiple docs containing values such as

widgets['Thingy', 'Whatsit', 'Thingyamybob', 'Big Thingy']

```
my-index/my-type/_search?pretty=true&typed_keys=true
{
  "aggs": {
    "filterAggs": {
      "filter": {
        "match": {
          "widgets": {
            "query": "t"  <- will filter all the docs that match the autocomplete filter.
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
       "bucketAggs": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "widgets.keyword", <- Will bring back all the values in the matched docs, including the ones that didn't match, e.g. 'Whatsit'
            "include": "t.*",  <- This is the closest I've got but it's using regex and not the autocomplete filter.
            "size": 7
          }
        }
      }
    }       
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

Without the `"include": "t.*"` I get all the values including the non matching 'Whatsit'.  `"include": "t.*"` is using regex which is not the same method as the match query and will give different results, it's case sensitive, doesn't have ASCII folding etc.

Comment: your aggs query doesn't look right. don't know your mappings but if you just leave filter agg would that show expected number?

Comment: Cheers  @AndreyBorisko I messed up the nesting when converting my example from real world to something more generic, I've fix it now.  I'm not looking for the number.  I'm looking for all the values that match the auto complete.  The buckets include values that don't match. It has everything that is in the matching documents widget array, including non matching values.

Comment: ok, so let's forget about the nested agg for a sec. I'm asking about the count from filter agg. does it  return the expected number of records that it should match? or not?

Comment: Yes the counts are right, it's just the buckets contain values that don't match the query. I can see what it's doing.  It's creating buckets of the all the values in the array of the matching docs, not just the match values of that array.